# Unable to form cluster of 2 nodes in distributed cache using Infinispan

Tags: jboss, infinispan, distributed-cache

There are two scenarios as mentioned below.

**First Scenario:**

Node1: 192.168.**69**.201

Node2: 192.168.**69**.202

**Second Scenario:**

Node1: 192.168.**69**.201

Node2: 192.168.**68**.203

Cluster is formed successfully in the first scenario but not in the second one. I used TCP protocol as mentioned in the below xml:

```
<config xmlns="urn:org:jgroups"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:org:jgroups file:schema/JGroups-3.2.xsd">
    <TCP
            bind_addr="${jgroups.tcp.address:192.168.68.201}"
            bind_port="${jgroups.tcp.port:7800}"
            loopback="true"
            ...
             />

    <MPING bind_addr="${jgroups.bind_addr:192.168.68.201}" break_on_coord_rsp="true"
           mcast_addr="${jgroups.mping.mcast_addr:228.2.4.6}"
           mcast_port="${jgroups.mping.mcast_port:43366}"
           ip_ttl="${jgroups.udp.ip_ttl:2}"
           num_initial_members="3"/>
    ...
    ...
</config>
```

192.168.68.201 was replaced by respective IP address at a particular node.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely, multicast traffic is not allow to travel between 192.168.69.x and 192.168.68.x networks which is a common problem when using multicast based PING protocols (MPING). Either, talk to your network guys to allow multicast between those two subnets, or as suggested by Arjun, try using TCPPING specifying the IP addresses of the nodes to connect to. Here's an [example](http://www.jgroups.org/manual/html/user-advanced.html#d0e2475) of TCPPING configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Try using TCPPING instead of MPING